# Is it possible to translate a clojure syntax into python syntax?

Tags: python, clojure, translate

I have been looking around but haven't found an example of this.  I'd like to write out a few long/tedious python scripts using Clojure.  Just because I happen to enjoy Clojure a bit more and they are not full on programs.

This site makes me think it is possible:
http://jkkramer.com/sudoku.html

For example if I have script.clj, I'd like to be able to convert it to script.py - not by hand of course.

Is it possible to do this?  If so, what tool/library/script should I use?  If its not possible not, why not?

[Edit] I edited this because the wording mistakenly gave the impression I was looking for a detailed lesson on writing my own solution.  I was just curious if the tools were out there to answer my question and if not then why not.

Comment: Do you mean you want to convert python *to* clojure? Because that is not what the title says.

Comment: "As an exercise, I translated Peter Norvig’s Sudoku solver from Python to Clojure. " can be read in the blog post you referred to..

Comment: It sounds like you are describing a source-to-source compiler. Yes, it is certainly possible. ClojureScript compiles Clojure to Python, for example. How? Too broad for this site.

Comment: @A.Webb I believe you mean that ClojureScript compiles Clojure to *JavaScript*.

Comment: @verdammelt Yes, of course, addled brain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Write a compiler that takes Clojure syntax and outputs valid Python syntax.

**How** to do that is well outside of the ability/scope of a StackOverflow answer.

Also note that if you do this for the general case of compiling any piece of Clojure code to Python you will have implemented quite a bit of Clojure in Python (especially when you implement `defmacro` and generic methods).

Answer (score 3):

You actually don't have to do a source to source translation in order to write Clojure that will interact with python libraries. Just see [clojure-py](https://github.com/drewr/clojure-py) which allows you to write regular Clojure syntax and run it under the Python interpreter and call Python libraries.

Comment: @Uri I updated the link. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem the project ever got much traction and it also hasn't been maintained.